# Invoice Billing System in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, billing, invoice

I want to Develop a billing system in that i need item name, which comes from database (Combo box or Autosuggestion Type) When we Select the item Rate will come from database. after that when we enter qty the total will be displayed. after complete one line we can enter another. but i don't know how to deal with that which tool to use please help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to think first whether your system is web-based or desktop based.As u have tagged this question in vb.net I assume that you are sure to develop things in .net.

1.You can develop this using vb.net both as desktop based and web-based.

2.In any case you have to deal with database.like sql server for .net

3.You got to make tables and fetch the data which is a cakewalk in .net

4.Then insert the record and calculate the price and print the invoice if needed..

I think it will work as a roadmap for you

Comment: This is the best you will get, if you don't know how to use any of the languages or tools, i suggest some collage or books, no pun inteded, also an alternative is downloading the IDE of choice and start googling , how to create ( name of tool in name of ide ) , then google how to fill ( name of tool in name of ide in name of language )  and go from there